# How does one prevent text from breaking across pages in a PDF created by itext7.pdfhtml?

Tags: c#, html, css, itext7

I am using itext7 version 7.1.2 and itext7.pdfhtml version 2.0.2 to produce a PDF from some HTML containing elements which must not break across pages (e.g. graphs and their accompanying text).

I have tried using explicit page breaks (as was used successfully in our legacy iTextSharp solution (using `page-break-before: always` on any elements containing elements which should not be separated)) but these don't work at all so tried using the more preferable `page-break-inside: avoid` as a style on the element containing the elements which I did not want to break across multiple pages.  Here is a simplified version of the code which outputs the inline HTML as a PDF in your "My Documents" path...

```
using iText.Html2pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace IText7Html2PdfPageBreakTester
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var html = @"<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style=""font-size: 60pt"">
            Some Initial Text.
        </div>
        <div style=""page-break-inside: avoid; font-size: 120pt"">
            This text should all be on the same page.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>";
            var pdfFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Example PDF.pdf");

            Console.WriteLine($"Converting example HTML to PDF and writing the PDF to: \"{pdfFilePath}\".");

            using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfFilePath))
            {
                using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                {
                    var converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();

                    pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

                    using (var document = new Document(pdfDocument))
                    {
                        //NOTE: If this line is commented then the "page-break-inside: avoid" style behaves as expected.
                        document.SetMargins(40, 40, 40, 40);

                        foreach (var element in HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(html, converterProperties).OfType<IBlockElement>())
                            document.Add(element);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"PDF written to: \"{pdfFilePath}\".");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I was able to achieve the desired behaviour if no margins were set on the document; however, it is a business requirement that margins are set on the document so how can I both have these margins set and keep the `page-break-inside: avoid` behaviour?

I have also tried creating a custom `ITagWorker` to interpret a custom `<pageBreak/>` element I tried using instead as a workaround but was having no luck there getting the `ProcessorContext.GetPdfDocument().AddNewPage()` method to actually add a page.

**Supplement**: if you substitute the `html` variable with the following you can see that neither `page-break-before: always` nor `page-break-after: always` work as expected regardless of whether margins have been set on the document.

```
var html = @"<html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style=""page-break-after: always"">
                    Some Initial Text.
                </div>
                <div>
                    This text should be on a new page.
                </div>
                <div style=""page-break-before: always; font-size: 60pt"">
                    This text should be on a further new page.
                </div>
                <div style=""page-break-inside: avoid; font-size: 120pt"">
                    This text should all be on the same page.
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>";
```

Comment: I wonder about the phrase "it is a business requirement". Have you purchased a commercial license? If so, feel free to contact the iText Jira support board.

Comment: I'm not at liberty to disclose details here but I have been informed our company is not eligible for this support.  Is there any chance of getting an answer here on StackOverflow?

Comment: I have run into this issue as well. In my case I am not explicitly setting the margins and I am still seeing the issue. Anyone have any luck?