# iText HTML to PDF conversion not honoring style="page-break-inside: avoid;"

Tags: itext7

I am currently evaluating a number of html to pdf packages. Most seem to correctly insert a page break when using the following:

```
<tbody style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
```

However it does not seem to be working for me with iText7 7.1.2 and pdfHtml 2.0.2. Is there a particular converter property to set? Does this only work for some HTML elements?

**Note: ** One detail of this is that the input is an HTML stream, not a static file.

Comment: This looks to be the same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50372100/513847

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following question is similar and may answer your question that you're having about page breaks.

[how can I make a page break using itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198337/how-can-i-make-a-page-break-using-itext)

Comment: Thanks Dale. The input is streamed HTML, so at best manually adding the page breaks would be fragile in this scenario.

Comment: Good point.  In looking into this a bit more, I see there is another question that points to some other solutions that might work. I haven't looked into your particular issue, however, this might help you solve your problem.  Good luck.  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36861/free-for-commercial-use-java-library-to-convert-html-to-pdf

Comment: Thanks again Dale. There were a few other packages that did not have this issue with the page break css. We ended up choosing to go with SelectPDF for our solution.